# Front-end form with Craft CMS returning error: Request missing required body param

Tags: craftcms

I have copy pasted the form in the Craft CMS docs [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html) into my project. I receive the error: `Request missing required body param`

I found an answer on here that suggests I add:

`<input type="hidden" name="clients" value="{{craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('clients').id }}">`

However, it didn't change anything. I still receive the same error. The only thing I have set to `required` in the entry is the Title when I'm trying this form out.

Here's what I've tried:

```
{% macro errorList(errors) %}
        {% if errors %}
            <ul class="errors">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endmacro %}

    {# If there were any validation errors, an `entry` variable will be passed to the
       template, which contains the posted values and validation errors. If that’s not
       set, we’ll default to a new entry. #}
    {% set entry = entry ?? create('craft\\elements\\Entry') %}

    <form method="post"
          accept-charset="UTF-8"
    >
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
        {{ redirectInput('clients/') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('clients', '2') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}

        <input type="hidden"
               name="clients"
               value="{{ craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('clients').id }}"
        >

        <label for="title">Title</label>
        {{ input('text', 'title', entry.title, {
            id: 'title',
            class: entry.hasErrors('title') ? 'error',
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}


        <input type="submit"
               value="Publish"
        >
    </form>
```

since this wasn't working I tried to do the form a bit differently, but I couldn't get anything but my Title and Date Of Birth to actually submit to an entry:

```
{% extends "_layout.twig" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="container flex justify-around mt-10">
        <form method="post"
              action=""
              accept-charset="UTF-8"
        >
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="sectionId"
                   value="{{ craft.sections.getSectionByHandle('clients').id }}"
            >

            {{ csrfInput() }}
            {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
            {{ redirectInput('clients/index') }}
            {{ hiddenInput('clients', '2') }}
            {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}

            <label for="title">Name</label>
            <input id="title"
                   type="text"
                   name="title"
                   class="border block mb-5"
            >

            {% set currentValue = entry is defined and entry.dateOfBirth
                ? entry.dateOfBirth|date('Y-m-d', timezone='UTC')
                : '' %}
            <label for="dateOfBirth">Date Of Birth</label>
            <input type="date"
                   name="fields[dateOfBirth]"
                   value="{{ currentValue }}"
                   class="border block mb-5"#}
            >


            <h1 class="text-2xl mb-3">Address:</h1>
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input id="address"
                   type="text"
                   name="address"
                   class="border block mb-10"
            >
            <label for="city">City</label>
            <input id="city"
                   type="text"
                   name="city"
                   class="border block mb-10"
            >
            <label for="state">State</label>
            <input id="state"
                   type="text"
                   name="state"
                   class="border block mb-10"
            >
            <label for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
            <input id="zipcode"
                   type="text"
                   name="zipcode"
                   class="border block mb-10"
            >
            <h1 class="text-2xl mb-3">Phone Number:</h1>
            <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
            <input id="phoneNumber"
                   type="number"
                   name="phoneNumber"
                   class="border block mb-10"
            >

            <input type="submit"
                   value="Submit"
            >
            <pre>{{ dump(entry.getErrors()) }}</pre>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I made every field required and put a dump at the end so I could see what the errors were and it says every field but Title and Date Of Birth are blank.